# Promotion ideas when 3.2 will be released?

Tags: discussion, promotion

WordPress 3.2 is targeted to be released by the end of June. The first two betas have been released. As we are a site for WordPress experts, I think it would be nice if we would have interesting questions (and answers) about new features in 3.2 when it will be released.

This idea is inspired by a plan on the Gaming site, where Stack Exchange Inc. will [buy some new games and send them to community members](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/community-promotion-sponsorship-new-game-releases-for-community-members) so they can "seed" the site. Since we were so stupid to choose a free software project money is not an issue here, but we can use the advantage of an open source development model to have our questions done on at the same time the final version is released.

What do you think? And which new areas do you think you personally can cover? Do we have tags for all new topics? (Using [wordpress-3.2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-3.2) is [a bad idea](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/are-we-permanently-banning-the-wordpress-x-x-x-tags)).

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous commercial products where we could make this work, but I would not tie to WordPress 3.1; I would instead tie to the release of something relevant for the software. Categories:

- Themes
- Plugins
- Hosting Accounts
- Web Services

For example, some of the following companies could give free products or services to high-rep members here. Here are just a few that might be interested:

- WooThemes
- StudioPress Themes
- Organic Themes
- BackupBuddy
- Gravity Forms
- WPEngine
- ZippyKid
- Page.ly
- Scribe SEO
- YoLink Search

For this to work I would envision we create a community wiki to collectively edit the terms and conditions so that any of the people we designate as community leaders in the post (by nomination and enough votes?) could approach any vendor and propose they participate?

Comment: Ah, of course, there are premium plugins and themes in the WordPress ecosystem. I was only thinking about the upcoming release of 3.2 and how we could prepare for that, but maybe we could move your answer to a different question? (Although some premium providers get their money by providing premium support - would a free alternative like WPSE be welcomed by them?)

Comment: @Jan Fabry - I believe that those enlightened plugin and theme providers would see the exposure that WordPress Answers could provide as a great benefit to them. I see WPSE as a great place for "How To" questions vs. asking about bugs or feature requests, etc.