# Restrict the scope of the tag "wordpress-version"

Tags: discussion, tags

We have banned the `wordpress-$number` tags [a long time ago](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/are-we-permanently-banning-the-wordpress-x-x-x-tags). Unfortunately, many askers are using the tag `wordpress-version` now as a replacement. Most of these questions are not about versioning, they are about updates, a topic with its own tag.

I want to restrict the `wordpress-version` tag to versioning and nothing else. Topics under this tag would include:

- How are WordPress versions generated?
- How can I find out the version?
- How can I hide it?

Updates or specific versions should be excluded; in these cases the tag doesn't help finding related topics anyway.

Before I do that: Do you have any objections?

Answer (score 2):

I'm cool with that. But as always setting the rule will be easier than policing it.

Comment: I am policing the tags `wordpress.org`, `wordpress.com` and `wordpress-version` actively. They are my pets, hence the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

One week later, I have changed the [tag info](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/wordpress-version/info) and started retagging. I will try not to pollute the front page with my edits, so this will take some time until it's finished.